# Best way to set up Node.js logging for app hosted on 2 EC2's with ELB

Tags: node.js, amazon-ec2, amazon-cloudwatch, pm2

I have 2 separate but identical instances of an app spinning on two EC2s connected with an Elastic Load Balancer (ELB).

I would like to know the best way you have found to be able to store and retrieve logs from node to troubleshoot issues.

Some users are experimenting authentication/authorization issues and want to put a couple of `console.log(usefulStuffToLog)`and be able to read it from the AWS console, CloudWatch.

Comment: Interesting. Take a look at this document https://github.com/goldbergyoni/nodebestpractices#2-error-handling-practices, it may help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you configure pm2 to output its logs to a known location on ec2, you can use CloudWatch agent provided by aws to ship the logs to CloudWatch Logs for you.

Wherever your executing pm2, add either `-l` or `-e` and `-o` switches to [specify where to write your pm2 log files](https://pm2.keymetrics.io/docs/usage/log-management/):

```
-l --log [path]              specify filepath to output both out and error logs
-o --output <path>           specify out log file
-e --error <path>            specify error log file
```

[Install CloudWatch agent](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/Install-CloudWatch-Agent.html). Agent can also be used to send instance metrics like available disk space etc. There is a [wizard included with CWAgent](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/create-cloudwatch-agent-configuration-file.html) to help create the json config file which is a good starting point but might require some manual tweaking.

You need to provide credentials for CWAgent - it can use the instance profile credentials, or you can configure the agent with a APIkey and secret.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I think this is what I need to know. I was hoping EC2 had some built in integration with CloudWatch but I'm sure this would work great. I will try it out!